# Specify MPEG-4 as encoding parameter in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, codec

I want to ask about **mpeg4** codec parameters. I use it to encode video in Evalvid environment as follows:

```
./ffmpeg -s cif -r 30 -b 64000 -bt 3200 -g 30 -i raw.yuv -vcodec mpeg4 vid.m4v
```

The video will be encoded using the MPEG-4 codec. What are the specific parts from MPEG-4 that will be taken if `mpeg4` is added as encoding parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It encodes MPEG-4 Part 2, as used by the XviD/DivX encoders. If you want MPEG-4 Part 10, also known as MPEG-4 AVC or H.264, use the encoder `libx264` instead.

It uses the Simple Profile by default (`Simple@L1` to be precise).

Comment: Without specifying anything else it uses the Simple profile. No idea how to get ASP or others, as I've never had to work with MPEG-4 Part 2 a lot.

Comment: @slhck as always, I bow to your superior knowledge :)

Comment: Okay, it uses Simple profile if (and only if) neither B-frames nor Qpel motion compensation are enabled, or if you specify it through `profile` (no idea what the options are). See `mpeg4_encode_visual_object_header` in `mpeg4videoenc.c`.